# Add bullets to subsections

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I want to add bullets or diamonds in front of subsections.

I know the method of adding items, i.e.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item First bullet point 
    \item Another bullet point 
    \item Add as many bullet points as you want
\end{itemize}
```

But actually I need bullets for subsection and NOT USING `itemize`.
I searched for this problem. I am very new to LaTeX ,so can anyone help?

Comment: Technically, the definition of subsection depends on the document class, although I suspect all of them are similar.

Comment: Please provide a small example (»MWE«) that includes things like your documentclass, the fonts you use, and all that seems necessary to show us, how your document will look. By the way, should your subsections be numbered?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you aren't using a table of contents or using the subsection numbers as part of the figure captions or equation numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\heading}[1]% #1 = text
{\par\vskip 1.5ex \@plus .2ex
 \hangindent=1em
 \noindent\makebox[1em][l]{$\,\bullet$}\textbf{\large #1}%
\par\vskip 1.5ex \@plus .2ex
\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{first}
\subsection{subsection}% for comparison
Note that first paragraph is not indented.
\heading{heading}
Note that first paragraph is not indented.
\heading{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]